# Error: $x = 1\iff x = \pm 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: Equation development]

What's the error in this equation/solution?

The correct answer should  be ***$x = 1 ⇒ x = ±1$***, right?

***Here's my attempt:***
For $x=-1$, I can't "come back" from the first line to $x=1$. I get $4=0$ as a result.
However, for $x=1$, I can do this procedure and find $0=0$.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: $x^2-2x+1=0$  does not imply $x=1$? What other solution exists?

Comment: My mistake, Sorry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$(1)$ and $(2)$ are not equivalent.

As you can see, $(2)$ also holds for $x=-1$.

Comment: In this case, x^2 also holds x = -1, making the equation 0=0, but the "-2x" doesn't hold x = -1, right?
Sorry, but I don't know how to use MathJax.

Comment: @DanielSehnColao If I understand you correctly then it looks like you get the idea. It's true that $x^2 = 1$ whenever $x=1$ or $x=-1$. Indeed the important part is that once they insert $x=1$ in $-2x$ they change everything because it has different values for $x=1$ and $x=-1$.

Comment: Yes, if I insert x = -1 in -2x the equation will change at all. That's why (1) doesn't hold x = -1. And in the (2) I just have x^2, then it's okay to insert whether x = 1 or x = -1, right?

Comment: @DanielSehnColao Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 4):

The answer given is right. The second logical connective (*i.e.*, $\iff$) should be $\implies$.